# Oracle SQL how to eliminate duplicated row by specific column

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

for example I have values like below in one table

```
 Table A                          
 ----------------                 
 item_name price departure        
 ----------------                 
 shoe      10    150
 shoe      10    150              
 socks     2     100              
 socks     2     110
 shirt     5     170
 shirt     5     170            
 gloves    1     210  
 gloves    1     210
 gloves    1     210
```

I would like to select all rows with unique item_name so the simple method is using UNION

```
select item_name, price, departure from table A
UNION 
select item_name, price, departure from table A
```

but like you see socks have diffrent departure and my result is wrong because I got result

```
 Table A                          
 ----------------                 
 item_name price departure        
 ----------------                 
 shoe      10    150             
 socks     2     100              
 socks     2     110
 shirt     5     170          
 gloves    1     210
```

Can you help me, I looking simple method something without left join because the table A contains a lot of data and I want to optimize

i want to get result like below where socks have smallest department in same (item_name and price)

```
Table A                          
 ----------------                 
 item_name price departure        
 ----------------                 
 shoe      10    150             
 socks     2     100              
 shirt     5     170          
 gloves    1     210
```

thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried with `select distinct`?

Comment: distinct now working for all columns with diffrent departure, result will be same

Comment: `group by` and aggregation functions? (`array_agg`, `min`, `max`, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `row_number()` is an effective way of choosing a particular row from a table. Within the `over()` clause use `partition by` and `order by` to control when the row number is reset to 1:

> ```
> select
>     *
> from (
>     select
>          item_name
>        , price
>        , departure
>        , row_number() over(partition by  item_name order by price, departure) as rn
>     from mytable a  
>     ) d
> where rn = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> ITEM_NAME | PRICE | DEPARTURE | RN
> :-------- | ----: | --------: | -:
> gloves    |     1 |       210 |  1
> shirt     |     5 |       170 |  1
> shoe      |    10 |       150 |  1
> socks     |     2 |       100 |  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d88a8396c9c1d2a77a3ebf6a159ab571)*

Answer (score 1):

I think that you just need aggregation:

```
select item_name, price, min(departure) departure
from mytable
group by item_name, price
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=09c5298d2d31f4972fca6659adaca147)**:

```
ITEM_NAME | PRICE | DEPARTURE
:-------- | ----: | --------:
shoe      |    10 |       150
socks     |     2 |       100
shirt     |     5 |       170
gloves    |     1 |       210
```

Comment: this is working only with this case because if you have a lot of data always you got same min department for all duplicated rows

Comment: @worker555 . . . I interpret your comment as saying:  "this works for the question I asked".   And I think it is the simplest solution (and you should accept it).  If you have a different question, you should ask it as a *new* question.